# Change of integrals used in Gauss' Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

I have this question where in which the integrals are made from a volume to the integral only dependent on the radial distance R.
While they prove this in part b) of the answer in part a) they somehow arrive to the same results.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The equation you underlined with question marks is the result of integrating two out of three variables in the equation above it. That integral equation involves integrating over $dR$, $d\theta$, and $d\phi$ . There no dependency on $\theta$ and $\phi$ in $\rho_\nu(R)$. Therefore the integral over the two variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ results in a constant: $4\pi$.

$$
\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} sin \theta d\theta d\phi = 4\pi
$$

The result in a single integral over $dR$, which is then "solved" by the underlined equation.

Edit: To answer the follow-up question: "How did they integrate over R...?"

Aside: I realize by writing "solved" above that implies solving the integral. Instead the author solves the equation for $\rho$.

Answer: They didn't integrate. Instead they used the known result from part (a) to determine the answer.

First:
$$
Q = 4\pi R^{4}_{0} \epsilon_{0}
$$

This is simply repeating the equation in part (a).

Second:
$$
\int_{\nu} \rho_\nu(R) d\nu = Q
$$
This is the statement that the integral of the charge density is the total charge. And the total charge we determined by drawing the Gaussian surface around the cloud in part (a).

Thus the author isn't solving the integral directly, but instead writing the equation:
$$
\int_{\nu} \rho_\nu(R) d\nu = 4\pi R^{4}_{0} \epsilon_{0}
$$

then
$$
\int_{R=0}^{R_{0}} \rho_\nu(R) R^{2} dR = 4\pi R^{4}_{0} \epsilon_{0}
$$

and finally stating that the above equation is satisfied with the 'answer'.
$$
\rho_{\nu}(R) = 4R\epsilon_{0}
$$

Or to put it another way, the author writes the equation for $\int\rho = Q$, and plugs in everything they knows until they gets to the integral over $R$. Then they solve for $\rho$ by taking the derivative of both sides of the equation.

P.S. I am going to assume the symbol $p_\nu$ is a typo for $\rho_{v}$ because otherwise this all wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, and how did they integrate p(R) without doing the divergence like in part b?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your follow-up question.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense! Thank you